# juju bootstrap controller unable to contact api server after 1 attempts: unable to connect to API: Forbidden

Tags: juju, openstack

I am trying to create a offline install of charmed kubernetes with openstack. Following the canonical guides I have come stuck on this error. I think it is failing to populate `juju-proxy-systemd.conf` and `juju-proxy.conf` with the no-proxy details?

To run juju bootstrap controller i run

```
juju bootstrap --bootstrap-series=$OS_SERIES \
  --metadata-source=~/simplestreams \
  --model-default network=test \
  --model-default external-network=external \
  --model-default use-floating-ip=true \
  --config use-default-secgroup=true \
--config apt-http-proxy=http://proxy.co.uk:3128 \
--config apt-ftp-proxy=ftp://proxy.co.uk:3128 \
--config apt-https-proxy=http://proxy.co.uk:3128 \
--config apt-no-proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0,127.0.1.1,127.0.1.1,local.home,10.255.52.0/24,10.20.20.0/24,192.168.122.0/24 \
--config juju-http-proxy=http://proxy.co.uk:3128 \
--config juju-ftp-proxy=ftp://proxy.co.uk:3128 \
--config juju-https-proxy=http://proxy..co.uk:3128 \
--config juju-no-proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0,127.0.1.1,127.0.1.1,local.home,10.255.52.0/24,10.20.20.0/24,192.168.122.0/24 \
--config snap-http-proxy=http://proxy.co.uk:3128 \
--config snap-ftp-proxy=ftp://proxy.co.uk:3128 \
--config snap-https-proxy=http://proxy.co.uk:3128 \
--config snap-no-proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0,127.0.1.1,127.0.1.1,local.home,10.255.52.0/24,10.20.20.0/24,192.168.122.0/24 \
--config logging-config="<root>=TRACE;unit=TRACE" \
 --debug \
  microstack microstack
```

To run charmed kubernetes local install i run

```
juju bootstrap \
--config logging-config="<root>=TRACE;unit=TRACE" \
 --debug \
--config apt-no-proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,local.home,10.255.52.0/24,10.20.20.0/24,192.168.122.0/24 \
--config juju-no-proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,local.home,10.255.52.0/24,10.20.20.0/24,192.168.122.0/24 \
localhost localhost8
```

Both commands fail at

```
22:30:30 ERROR juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:884 unable to contact api server after 1 attempts: unable to connect to API: Forbidden
22:30:30 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:885 (error details: [{/build/snapcraft-juju-a284566302ade03f36071a6fe755224b/parts/juju/src/cmd/juju/common/controller.go:153: unable to contact api server after 1 attempts} {/build/snapcraft-juju-a284566302ade03f36071a6fe755224b/parts/juju/src/cmd/juju/common/controller.go:50: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-a284566302ade03f36071a6fe755224b/parts/juju/src/cmd/modelcmd/modelcommand.go:421: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-a284566302ade03f36071a6fe755224b/parts/juju/src/cmd/modelcmd/modelcommand.go:440: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-a284566302ade03f36071a6fe755224b/parts/juju/src/cmd/modelcmd/base.go:275: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-a284566302ade03f36071a6fe755224b/parts/juju/src/juju/api.go:83: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-a284566302ade03f36071a6fe755224b/parts/juju/src/api/apiclient.go:218: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-a284566302ade03f36071a6fe755224b/parts/juju/src/api/apiclient.go:686: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-a284566302ade03f36071a6fe755224b/parts/juju/src/api/apiclient.go:1028: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-a284566302ade03f36071a6fe755224b/parts/juju/src/api/apiclient.go:1132: unable to connect to API} {/build/snapcraft-juju-a284566302ade03f36071a6fe755224b/parts/juju/src/api/apiclient.go:1157: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-a284566302ade03f36071a6fe755224b/parts/juju/src/api/apiclient.go:737: } {Forbidden}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is failing to populate juju-proxy-systemd.conf and juju-proxy.conf with the no-proxy details?

You can try to set the proxy settings in the juju config file:

$HOME/.juju/environments.yaml

For example:

environments:
maas:
type: maas
maas-server: 'http://192.168.1.1/MAAS'
maas-oauth: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
default-series: xenial
bootstrap-timeout: 1800
bootstrap-retry-delay: 10
bootstrap-addresses-delay: 10
admin-secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
authorized-keys-path: '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'
proxy-http: http://proxy.co.uk:3128
proxy-https: https://proxy.co.uk:3128
proxy-ftp: ftp://proxy.co.uk:3128
no-proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1,local.home,10.255.52.0/24,10.20.20.0/24,192.168.122.0/24

You can also set the proxy settings in the environment variables:

http_proxy=http://proxy.co.uk:3128
https_proxy=https://proxy.co.uk:3128
ftp_proxy=ftp://proxy.co.uk:3128
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,local.home,10.255.52.0/24,10.20.20.0/24,192.168.122.0/24

For more information, please refer to:

https://docs.jujucharms.com/2.5/en/controllers-config